# Set selected tab without selectedIndexChanged event firing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, tabcontrol

Is there a way to set the selected tab of a tabControl without the selectedIndexchanged event firing?

e.g. Here the event fires when selecting myTabPage2 because myTabPage1 is the default:

```
Private Sub setupTabControl
    If blnHasAccount=true then
       MyTabControl.selectedTab=myTabPage1
    else
       MyTabControl.selectedTab=myTabPage2
    End if
End sub

Private Sub MyTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyTabControl.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Do stuff (but only when user has actually changed the tab themselves)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the new tabpage you could remove the event handler

```
Try
    RemoveHandler MyTabControl.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Me.MyTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged
    .. do your works to change page here
    .. and then reconnect
Finally
    AddHandler MyTabControl.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Me.MyTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged
End Try
```

It's important to enclose everything in a Try Finally to recover correctly from exceptions

Answer (score -2):

One could falsify and check ComboBox.Enabled as a flag to use in the SelectedIndexChanged event while making changes then set back to true when done. Such events will still fire however (should they?) but at least you can assure status of the Global 'ComboBox' Variable.

Comment: Please see [answer]